# What is the correct way to read this github's ocaml compiler project with bash scripts involved?

Tags: ocaml

https://github.com/nlsandler/nqcc

At the above link, there is the compiler created by the author of this blog: https://norasandler.com/2017/11/29/Write-a-Compiler.html

I read through the first post and was faced with the problem that I almost always face when looking at a project on Github. Where to start?

I know the syntax for OCaml more or less, so I can read a single OCaml program and sort of understand what it does, but with a project at this level, I don't even know where the files of src/ are being called! You call the nqcc, and then what happens? How do we get to the ml files in src/? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. Could someone guide me in how to navigate a huge project like this effectively?

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question itself. This question and its answers are not going to make any sense when the external resources inevitably change or get removed. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it involves understanding the build system, but your particular example is pretty easy to understand and is very transparent.

You need to know only two rules:

1. a binary `foo` corresponds to file `foo.ml`;
2. a module `Foo` corresponds to file `Foo.ml`<sup>1</sup>.

By applying these rules, we can figure out that `nqcc.ml` is the entry point. It calls the `compile` function which has the following definition (copied here for the ease of reference)

```
let compile prog_filename =
    let source_lines = File.lines_of prog_filename in
    let ast = Enum.reduce (fun line1 line2 -> line1^" "^line2) source_lines
    |> Lex.lex
    |> Parse.parse
    in
    Gen.generate prog_filename ast
```

So it refers to `File`, `Enum`, `Lex`, `Parse`, and `Gen` modules. The first two comes from the outside of the project (from the `batteries` library, which provides an extension to the OCaml standard library). While the last three correspond to `lex.ml`, `parse.ml`, and `gen.ml` files correspondingly.

---

<sup>1)</sup>) An optional but useful third rule:

3. a module `Foo` has the interface file named `foo.mli`

The interface file is sort of like a header file and make contain only types, and usually contains documentation.

Comment: If we were to run this from the terminal, then we would be running this I think:     `\`dirname $0\`/nqcc.byte $1 #compile to assembly`, not nqcc.ml.. Does the machine already know byte means ml for OCaml?

Comment: No, neither machine nor operating system, which runs on a machine, know how to run programs in any language other than a machine language. You have to compile your program fiiles or pass them as an input to an interpreter of the corresponding language, like java, for example. So, if you were to run it from a terminal, then you have to follow the installation instructions, specified in their GitHub page, to compile and install the necessary binaries. And the `nqcc` wrapper shell scipt makes it easier to use the compiled tool and acts as a simple driver for it.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff in `src/` gets compiled to `nqcc.byte` by `setup.ml`, which is run by the `Makefile`. `setup.ml` knows to do this by looking at the `_oasis` file, because all it does is call out to an ocaml build framework called OASIS. The `nqcc` shell script runs `$(dirname $0)/nqcc.byte $1`, which means "call the executable `nqcc.byte` in the same directory as this script, with the script's first argument".

How do you do this in general? Well, mostly experience. But starting with the `Makefile` or other build script is usually a good way to figure out what the main components are and how they hang together.